# Corpus of tagged text (English newspapers or any tagged text)

Tags: english, corpora, resource-request

I'm developing a system to extract tags from text (English) and currently I have no dataset to test the system and evaluate, could someone point me to a source (preferably a free one)
thanks

SO I Managed To Find What I was looking For On Github
IF anyone is struggling with similar issue here is the link
https://github.com/snkim/AutomaticKeyphraseExtraction

Comment: What kind of tagging you have in mind? POS tagged?

Comment: While this kind of question is clearly on-topic here, the opendata stackexchange http://opendata.stackexchange.com might be an alternative place to ask. And please be more explicit what "tag" means to you.

Comment: ok, thank you and by tagging I mean something like if there's an article talking about new discovery by nasa Tags should be ["Nasa","new Discovery"] something along these lines